# AngularJS xeditable - rename button in table far from displayed value

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I have the following table. The button "Rename 2" in the row with the value displayed works okey. But how to get the "Rename 1" work?

```
<table ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="v in vendors">
      <button ng-click="vendorForm.$show()" ng-hide="vendorForm.$visible">Rename 1</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="v in vendors">
      <span editable-text="v.name" e-form="vendorForm">{{v.name}}</span>
      <button ng-click="vendorForm.$show()" ng-hide="vendorForm.$visible">Rename 2</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['xeditable']);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.vendors = {
            1: { name: "first" },
            2: { name: "second" },
            3: { name: "third" }
          }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imikh/tupLu0cz/)